# Highcharts & Angularjs: update chart from $broadcast in the main controller doesn't update the chart like a $watch would in the chart's controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

By request, I will simplify my question.. but because it interacts with an API on a localhost, I cant replicate the issue on a jsfiddle. I'll break down my question to the details of whats happening between main and child controller...

Main controller: Scope contains a Company ID and accesses data from an API using a get function.

Child controller: Inherits the objects returned from the API and injects the data into a highchart. This controller also contains a $watchCollection for a UI that traverses the data in the highchart.

My problem is this: When the Company ID in the parent scope is changed and the API gets new data, the chart is not willing to update right away because the $watchCollection does not include stuff from the parent scope.

I know that the idea would be to $broadcast a change to the child controller and update accordingly, but the chart continues to not update until a change is made on the UI, which triggers the $watchCollection.

What can I do to somehow force the chart to trigger the $watchCollection when the parent scope changes?

Comment: Too much info, try to simplify or better give some demo in Plunker/Fiddle how it works today and expected results. Thanks,

Comment: 1. The problem is very likely lying in the way you "grab new data", but you don't give that info (how exactly do you "grab new data"). 2. Theoretically, a child-scope prototypically inherits the parent-scope's properties, so you should be able to `$watch` `currentCoId` directly. Are you sure this doesn't work (maybe you messed somethingup).

Comment: Indeed it **[seems to be possible](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/3Rj9S/)** to `$watch` properties of the parent scope.

Comment: Wow... This made me feel really stupid. The problem was that I had tried to include currentCoId in the watchCollection, when instead I needed to watch to the actual data that was being returned for changes instead of the company id. Thanks so much for helping me wrap my head around this. If you want to go ahead and submit an answer, I'll approve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A child-scope prototypically inherits the parent-scope's properties, so you should be able to `$watch` `currentCoId` or the data directly.

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/3Rj9S/)**.

(Note that **[`$watchCollection()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watchCollection)** only detects adding/deleting/moving items in a collection and does not watch their their content.)